# DateTime function and substring in vf page

Tags: datetime

I want to substring my datetime field in vf page.In my vf page i am using code like.

```
<div>{!LEFT(d.datetime__c,8)}</div>
```

here i am getting error LEFT function required text type.. So how i can subString my datetime field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
<div>{!LEFT(TEXT(d.datetime__c),8)}</div>
```

LEFT functions takes String value but here you are passing Date value that's why you are getting this Error. So convert Date to String Using `TEXT` function inside LEFT function first.

Comment: not working... Error: Unknown function String.valueOf. Check spelling

Comment: <div>{!LEFT(TEXT(d.datetime__c),8)}</div> . try this. Let me know whether it works or not

Comment: Hi thanks it works. i have used {!RIGHT((LEFT(TEXT(data.Date__c),10)) , 5)} to display date and month i.e 08-03 is it possible to replace '-' to '/' so that i can display date as 08/03

Comment: You supposed to vote up answers if it helps. you can also select as best anser

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify, why do you want use LEFT function here, we can use some datetime methods directly in VF page as mentioned below

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm

Comment: how we can display date and month by using datetime methods? all methods have specific default format to display..

Comment: {!DAY(data.Date__c)} - returns day  similarly {!Month(data.Date__c)}- returns month, we can display by combining two

Comment: Ya we can use if Date__c is date type but it is datetime type..

Comment: Yes, ur rite, day and month functions works with date but we can make them work with date time also  like below  {!Day(DATEVALUE(NOW()))} {!Month(DATEVALUE(NOW()))} i just used DATEVALUE function used for converting datetime to date.

Comment: ya got thanks this also working but it is displaying only single digit i.e 5 not 05 for day. Is it possible to display 05 if it is 5?

Answer (score 0):

IF you are attempting to get Date/month/ you can use the below code

```
DATE:  {! DAY(DATEVALUE(NOW()))}
MONTH: {! MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW()))}
YEAR:  {! YEAR(DATEVALUE(NOW()))}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to use this in Apex... but getting error

```
String DayName;
Date myDt;
myDt = date.parse(newDt); 
datetime mydttm = datetime.newInstance(myDt.year(), myDt.month(), myDt.day());

DayName = mydttm.format('EEE');
DayName = LEFT(DayName,3);

syntax error at 

    DayName = LEFT(DayName,3);
    Method does not exist or incorrect signature: LEFT(String, integer)
```